# Socket.io Why am I getting Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server

Tags: amazon-web-services, sockets, socket.io

Why am I getting the following error from my server? On socket.io when I can reach the socket.io via browser?

Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server.

You can hit the site and socket.io says hello.

```
http://produ-Publi-18S2BX3E0BF4K-2059687405.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
```

When my app tries to reach it I get a failed to load

```
http://produ-publi-18s2bx3e0bf4k-2059687405.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:8080/socket.io/1/?t=1558154228361
```

Server:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
  String.prototype.startsWith = function (str){
    return this.slice(0, str.length) == str;
  };
}

function log_me(msg){
  var ts = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (3600000*4));
  var tss = ts.toString();
  tss = tss.substring(0, tss.indexOf(' GMT'));
  console.log(tss + ": " + msg);
}

var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);
io.set('log level', 2);
io.set('transports', ['flashsocket']);
io.set('origins', '*:*');

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('join_channel', function(channel){
    log_me("join_channel: " + channel);
    socket.channel = channel;
    socket.join(channel);
  });
  socket.on('proceed', function(channel, data){
    log_me("proceed: " + channel + " - " + data);
    io.sockets.in(channel).emit('proceed', data);
  });
  socket.on('instruct', function(channel, data){
    log_me("instruct: " + channel + " - " + data);
    io.sockets.in(channel).emit('instruct', data);
  });
  socket.on('status_update', function(channel, data){
    log_me("status_update: " + channel + " - " + data);
    io.sockets.in(channel).emit('status_update', data);
  });
  socket.on('ambulance_move', function(channel, data){
    io.sockets.in(channel).emit('ambulance_move', data);
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    log_me("disconnect: " + socket.channel);
    if(socket.channel){
      if(socket.channel.startsWith("a_")){
        var c = socket.channel.replace("a_", "");
        var data = {'amb_id' : c, 'status' : 'DISCONNECTED'}
        io.sockets.in(c).emit('status_update', JSON.stringify(data));
      }
    }
    socket.leave(socket.channel);
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to hit port 80 in your browser, but port 8080 everywhere else? That's the one place I don't see a port number.

Comment: You are correct. Why is the browser using 80 (it is connecting on port 80), but I am setting the server to be port 8080 (its failing). I don't understand why the browser isn't using 8080 and why 80 would work when I set 8080.